# Vim folding introduces strange comments into the code automatically

Tags: vim, vi

I noticed that vim introduces strange comments into the code when I try to do folding.

Take this code, as an example:

```
<div class="ev_i_ctg">
    <!-- Category Icon -->
    <div class="ev_ic_ty FOA-bannerimage"></div>
    <!-- Number of attachments -->
    <div class="ev_ic_n">2</div>
</div>
```

When I try to fold the outer tag using the command `zfat`, it folds accordingly, but also adds extra stuff like the code shown below:

```
<div class="ev_i_ctg"><!--{-->
    <!-- Category Icon -->
    <div class="ev_ic_ty FOA-bannerimage"></div>
    <!-- Number of attachments -->
    <div class="ev_ic_n">2</div>
</div><!--}-->
```

The issue seems to occur randomly without any pattern whatsoever (or, at least, I couldn't find any). Why does it happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first step is `:help zf`. This explains

> This only works when 'foldmethod' is "manual" or "marker".
>   Also see |fold-create-marker|.

Following that, we get this explanation:

> Vim will append the start and end marker, as specified with
>   'foldmarker'.  The markers are appended to the end of the line.
>   'commentstring' is used if it isn't empty.

So, you have configured *marker-based folding*, your HTML (-dialect) filetype sets `'commentstring'` to `<!--%s-->`, and Vim will insert that.

Remedy: Switch to another folding method; usually, syntax-based folding is used with HTML. In `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/html.vim`, put:

```
setlocal foldmethod=syntax
```